# Is "Qadaqan" Mongolian or Turkish?

Tags: etymology, turkish, persian, mongolian

In Persian, the word *Qadaqan* (*q* is an uvular stop consonant, i.e. having the same place of articulation as the French *r*) means "emphasis" and "illegal", in some Persian dictionaries it is mentioned as a Turkic word, and some say it's Mongolian and in a linguistics book I read it's native Persian. I want someone who knows Turkic or Mongolian to tell me is this word from that origins?

Comment: Turkish has no uvular consonants, while Mongolian has /ɢ/ (voiced plosive), so my guess would be Mongolian based on that alone.

Comment: It might help if you could give it in Persian script.

Comment: In Persian script: غدغن

Comment: @Draconis It doesn't have to be modern Turkish per se. Lots of Turkic languages have uvular consonants, e.g., Tatar. Kyrgyz, Kazakh, Qaraqalpaq, Crimean, Karachay, Bashkir, Uyghur and Kumyk (possibly more) even have uvulars in their very names!! And, several others have at least a velar fricative. Besides, based on cultural exchanges between Turks and Iranians throughout history (definitely more than Mongolians and Iranians), I'd guess a Turkic origin is much more likely.

Comment: @sami.spricht.sprache Fair! I was assuming the asker wanted Turkish as in the title rather than Turkic as in the body of the question.

Comment: @Draconis Cool, I wasn't trying to be hostile :) But I think that it makes much more sense if the question was about Turkic languages as opposed to modern Turkish, as Persian is not especially likely to borrow anything from such a "new" language. [Historically, Turkish did possess a velar/uvular fricative ⟨ğ⟩ that has been lost in the modern language.] Besides if the word is a recent borrowing, we would likely know its origin (hence, making the question irrelevant).

Comment: @Draconis. Please look at my answer.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B0%D1%85 ?

Answer (score 3):

The modern Persian word pronounced /γadaγan/ means “prohibition” and the like; it is spelt both as غدغن and as قدغن. It can hardly be a native Persian word. I have searched for it in Clauson’s “Etymological dictionary of pre-thirteenth-century Turkish” (do note that Clauson uses “Turkish” to include all Turkic languages), as well as in several dictionaries of modern (Anatolian) Turkish, but found nothing.

It occurs, however, in the Urmi dialect of Neo-Aramaic. In his dictionary of that language Geoffrey Khan derives it via Azeri from Mongolian qadagala “to keep in confinement”.

Comment: Standard Anatolian Turkish has no word-initial γ.  Like half the words in Persian, it's in Azeri Turkish though: https://tr.wiktionary.org/wiki/qada%C4%9Fan  https://tr.wiktionary.org/wiki/qada%C4%9Fan_etm%C9%99k.  And Kurdish.  In case you have good etymological dictionaries for those.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer. Thank you for the reference to Azeri. I have edited my answer now.

Comment: Did you see en.wiktionary.org/wiki/хаах#Mongolian by the way?